# Prevent Special Characters in Datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, special-characters

How to prevent the special characters in datagridview in WPF using C#. Is there any any event for datagrid like KeyPress event.

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.Key))
{
    Control editingControl = (Control)sender;
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(editingControl.InputBindings + e.KeyChar, pattern))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Am using this above code, but its througing error,any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any any event for datagrid like KeyPress event.

Try the `PreviewTextInput` event:

```
<DataGrid ... PreviewTextInput="dg_PreviewTextInput">
```

---

```
private void dg_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, pattern))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Much mm8. your are rite, the wrong with the pattern only., its helped me lot Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]");
       if (!regex.IsMatch(e.Text))
            e.Handled = true;
```

This helped me, Thanks mm8...